# MySQL LIMIT with OFFSET not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

PreparedStatement ps is working as expected with user_type being updated for the first row however, my second statement (ps1) which should update the second row isn't. As the only change is the offset 'LIMIT 1, 1;' I can only assume that's why the system throws a MYSQLSyntaxErrorException. I'm new to MySQL so unsure why it's throwing an exception and how to achieve the same by trying something else.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/child_timer", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_profile SET user_type=? ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 1;");
    ps.setString(1, sp.getUserType().name());
    int x = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (x > 0) {
        alertDialogBuilder(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Success", null, "Changes have been successfully saved.");
    } 
                
    PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_profile SET user_type=? ORDER BY user_id ASC LIMIT 1, 1;");
    ps1.setString(1, sp.getUserType1().name());
    int x1 = ps1.executeUpdate();
    if (x1 > 0) {
        alertDialogBuilder(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Success", null, "Changes have been successfully saved.");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no offset in a MySQL Update LIMIT statement.
Provide a minimum id to create an offset instead like so:

```
wHERE user_id >= :offset
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the user_id auto_increments so if there are 3 user_profile's and user_id 1 gets deleted and a new user is created, the new user_profile will have user_id 4 so no guarantee that the second row would be updated in that statement. Any idea of how to make new user_profile's user_id to fill the lowest possible user_id instead?